# python/pandas - counting unique values in a single DataFrame column and displaying counts as new columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am starting with data of city transits with an additional column containing the mode of transportation

```
Orig   Dest    Type
NY     SF      Train
NY     SF      Plane
NO     NY      Plane
SE     NO      Plane
SE     NO      Train
```

I want to aggregate it such that each unique value in Type becomes a column with counts of that Type for each unique Orig/Dest pair

```
Orig  Dest  Plane  Train
NY    SF    1      1
NO    NY    1      0
SE    NO    1      1
```

I know some basic aggregation using pd.groupby but can only aggregate so far as to get just basic counts of the Orig/Dest pairs using:

```
df.groubpy(['Orig','Dest'])['Type'].count()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html). Last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print (df.groupby(['Orig','Dest', 'Type'])['Type']
         .nunique()
         .unstack()
         .fillna(0)
         .astype(int)
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

  Orig Dest  Plane  Train
0   NO   NY      1      0
1   NY   SF      1      1
2   SE   NO      1      1
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for